# Vampire movie about the making of Nosferatu

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

I remember seeing a movie when I was ten about the making of Nosferatu, but the character of Max Schreck was an actual vampire. I recall a scene with him explaining that he is too old to create other vampires and grabs a bat out of mid-air to eat. I would like to know the title of this movie.

Answer (score 18):

The movie is [**Shadow of the Vampire**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0189998/) starring Willem Dafoe, John Malkovich, Udo Kier, and comedian Eddie Izzard. It was directed by E. Elias Merhige (director of the disturbing masterpiece [Begotten](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=455ohZRdbY8)).

Willem Dafoe played the vampire and looked like this:

[image]

In the movie he was a **real** vampire who caused havoc on the set by eating people like the script girl.

The trailer can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAn5uLNMmjk&feature=kp).